# Bootstrap bootbox overlay

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootbox

I am using bootbox plugin for my application.

http://bootboxjs.com/

Something like this

```
bootbox.dialog({
  message: "I am a custom dialog",
  title: "Custom title",
  buttons: {
    success: {
      label: "Success!",
      className: "btn-success",
      callback: function() {
        Example.show("great success");
      }
    },
    danger: {
      label: "Danger!",
      className: "btn-danger",
      callback: function() {
        Example.show("uh oh, look out!");
      }
    },
    main: {
      label: "Click ME!",
      className: "btn-primary",
      callback: function() {
        Example.show("Primary button");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The problem what i have is that is modal is opened and something dynamically is added to message when modal is opened, it goes down of the page, but opacity element black stay the same?

[image]

Please check picture with a problem i have :(

Comment: can you show your code using jsfiddle..

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using?  There was a known issue (15881: Modal: Fix backdrop not readjusting when height changes) that was resolved in v3.3.4.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a Bootstrap Modal issue than Bootbox specifically.

The cleanest solution is to constrain the content of your modal, rather than try to override how Bootstrap's overlay works. So, here's an example jsFiddle with a lot of content: https://jsfiddle.net/17jLxr2n/

If we add a simple CSS ruleset to our container, we can easily constrain the modal to a usable size, as shown in the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/17jLxr2n/1/):

```
.dynamic-modal-content
{
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

The selector you use should be whatever container your dynamic content is returned with.